# How to select only one country in AM charts javascript?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want the country previously selected to be unselected when I select a new country.
I tried this code, besides other things which did not give me the desired output.
When I am clicking on second country after first one, first one is deselected but when I hover again, first country is again colored as selected.

```
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function (event) {
    if (currentActive) {
        currentActive.setState("default");
    }
    chart.maxZoomLevel = 32;
    currentActive = event.target;
    currentActive.properties.fill = colorSet.getIndex(4);
    chart.maxZoomLevel = 32;
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you used [this](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/selecting-multiple-areas-map/) example.

First you should define an `active` state for your map:

```
var activeState = polygonTemplate.states.create("active");
activeState.properties.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(4);
```

In your `hit` event callback you now can toggle `event.target.isActive` and reset the active state from the previous selected country.

```
var currentActive;
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  if (currentActive) {
    currentActive.isActive = false;
  }
  currentActive = ev.target;
  currentActive.isActive = true;
});
```

I created a ([code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moeaWV)) as reference. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. It really helped me.